# Most efficient way to sort list/array (calculate distance between objects in 3D space)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array that consists of objects like these:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, location, otherAttributes...):
        self.location = location
        self.otherAttributes...
arrayToSort = np.array([many times of type A], dtype=A)
```

Where location is a list with floating point numbers `location = [X, Y, Z]` that represent a location in a 3D space.

In every iteration of the program, it is necessary to get the distance between the objects. Also, in every iteration, the location of the objects will change and things will happen if the objects are within a certain range of each other. My idea was to sort the array after every iteration to quickly (O(log(n))) search for other object that are within a specific range.

Is that the best approach? If yes, what is the quickest way to sort this array first by X, then Y and then Z? In another thread the usage of `operator.itemgetter / operator.attrgetter` was suggested to avoid unnecessary function calls but I don't really know how that would apply in this case and that even makes sense here.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand exactly what you mean by "search for other object that are within a specific range". Are you looking to find all objects that are under a certain distance from each other, or all objects that are under a certain distance from one common point?

Comment: Both, actually.

Comment: Sorting (like many other Numpy operation) will be very slow on an array containing pure-Python objects because Numpy cannot use SIMD instructions. It cannot even use an efficient compiled C code to do that. The sort will call slow interpreted pure-Python functions a lot of time. If you want fast Numpy operation, you need to use Numpy structured types or multiple array of simple native types. The latter is generally very fast. Besides this, the general way to solve your problem is to use KD-trees. Scipy provide such a data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try to split the space into cubes of a predefined size. Then for each object add an attribute indicating to which cube it belongs (this is an easy computation based based on the value of each coordinate separately). Finally, if required, compute distances between objects in adjacent cubes only. This is a very basic type of geohashing, but it might be helpful.